# Efficient ways to filter in QGIS for the web

Tags: postgis, framework

I'm trying to upload a project to the G3W framework and I've noticed that the upload is extremely slow.
Are there any ways of optimizing the desktop QGIS project?
Since I have to implement filters on point-type geometries, I created some views in PostGIS. I loaded the view as a layer.
Is there any other, more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

g3wsuite has some recomendations on the web to improve performance, and also some settings can help:

- [Performance recomendations](https://g3w-suite.readthedocs.io/en/v3.6.x/projectsettings.html#performances-optimization).
- Settings that can help:

  - [Caching settings](https://g3w-suite.readthedocs.io/en/v3.6.x/settings.html#caching-settings)
  - [Gunicorn settings](https://g3w-suite.readthedocs.io/en/v3.6.x/docker_env.html#gunicorn-settings)
  - And also the [settings to configure QGIS Server](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/config.html)

Getting a good performance in this kind of application should be done based on your use case, and its difficult to give a general advice.

For your concrete case as you are asking about "filters on point-type geometries" my advise is not to use views, instead use database indexes.

You can use something like [pg_stats_staments](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) to get an idea of the queries done in your database, or just log all queries to really understand how the filters are translated to the database.

Then use function indexes. For example imagine that you have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(a.geom), b.geom)
```

You can create an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON a USING GIST(ST_PointOnSurface(geom));
ANALYZE a;
```